# C# Xamarin forms Nested Listiews in TabbedPage with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, observable

I am trying to create different tabs with different nested `ListViews` binding to `ObservableCollection`.
This is getting a bit over my head. It should be very simple to solve.

This is how my `TabbedPage` xaml looks like

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="scorePredict.Views.TabbedItemsPage" ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage Title="{Binding description}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DetailedViewModel.sortedItems}">
                        <ListView.HeaderTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="Time" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextColor="Gold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="50"/>
                                    <Label Text="Host" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,0,170,0"/>
                                    <Label Text="Guest" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Gold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="110,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Label Text="TIP" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="Gold" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

                        <ListView.Header  >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,5,0,5" BackgroundColor="Green" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ListView.Header>

                        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell Height="30">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             BackgroundColor="Goldenrod"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding imagePath}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Intro} " VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Summary}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="TIP" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <Grid Padding="5">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding TeamOne}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,0,170,0"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ScoreTeamOne}" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,50,0" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Gray"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ScoreTeamTwo}" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Gray"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding TeamTwo}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="110,0,0,0"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Tip}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="{Binding TipBGColor}"></Label>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                                <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Description}"></TextCell>-->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
</TabbedPage>
```

This is the background code

```
public TabbedItemsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new CurrentStatusDeviceViewModel();            
        }

public class CurrentStatusDeviceViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Things { set; get; }

        public CurrentStatusDeviceViewModel()
        {
            // Here I create three demo pages
            Things = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Things.Add(new TabViewModel(i.ToString()) { description = "description" + i });
            }
        }
    }

    public class TabViewModel
    {
        public string description { set; get; }

        public string TabID { set; get; }

        public CurrentStatusDeviceDetailedViewModel DetailedViewModel { set; get; }

        public TabViewModel(string tabID)
        {
            TabID = tabID;

            // Pass Tab ID to the second view model
            DetailedViewModel = new CurrentStatusDeviceDetailedViewModel(tabID);
        }
    }

    public class CurrentStatusDeviceDetailedViewModel
    {

        public string CurrentID { set; get; }
        public ObservableCollection<Titles> sortedItems { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; set; }

        public CurrentStatusDeviceDetailedViewModel(string tabId)
        {

            CurrentID = tabId;

            // I simulate the lists here
            sortedItems = new ObservableCollection<Titles>();
            items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                {
                    items.Add(new Item { Time = CurrentID + i, TeamOne = "Barcelona", ScoreTeamOne = "2", TeamTwo = "Real Madrid", ScoreTeamTwo = "1" });
                }
                sortedItems.Add(new Titles(items.ToList()) { Intro = "This is a big header", Summary = "This is the end" });
                items.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

And these are my classes for the lists

```
public class Titles : ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
        //public List<Matches> Monkeys { get; set; }
        public string Intro { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public Uri imagePath { get; set; }
        public Titles(List<Item> list) : base(list)
        {
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string TeamOne { get; set; }
        public string ScoreTeamOne { get; set; }
        public string ScoreTeamTwo { get; set; }
        public string TeamTwo { get; set; }
        public string Tip { get; set; }
        public Color TipBGColor { get; set; }
    }
```

My problem here is that the five headers are created but items are not created within them and the titles of the headers are not binded.
It is just empty.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the `IsGroupingEnabled` of ListView to `true` :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DetailedViewModel.sortedItems}" IsGroupingEnabled="True">
```

The document is here: [customizing-list-appearance#grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable grouping in your  Listview

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DetailedViewModel.sortedItems}" IsGroupingEnabled="True">
```